# Magento 2 - Update foreign key default to null in UpgradeSchema

Tags: magento2, database, upgradeschema

I created a foreign key in install schema for my custom table like this:

```
$custom_table->addColumn(
    'customer_id',
    \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
    null,
    ['nullable' => false,'unsigned' => true],
    'customer_id'
);
```

I set the nullable to false, now I want to make this foreign key column can take null as its value.

How can I set this in UpgradeSchema?

Comment: Set `'nullable' => true` and check it.